# How do I get grep to search for any number I put in the variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, server-administration

So at the beginning of my script, I am defining "threshold," which has a number that isn't going to exist in the next part, (2) and a number that will exist in the next part (6). I'm having the result of running `df -h` to a file called dffile. My question, is how do I get grep in line 7 to search all of the variable "threshold" for the number that will exist in the file? It works if I have the 6 before the 2 in the variable, so it seems as if it's only searching the first number in it. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

threshold=("2%" "6%")

df -h > dffile

grep $threshold dffile >> thresh

cat thresh | awk '{print $6}' >> finding1

LINES=()
while IFS= read -r finding1
do
find $finding1 -xdev -size +40M -exec ls -lah {} \; | head -n 10
done < "finding1"
```

The output of `df -h` on my test server is:

```
root@tstd0001:~/scripts# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            481M     0  481M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  616K   98M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        25G  1.3G   23G   6% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.4M  102M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
```

As you can see above, "2" from my variable, does not exist, whereas "6" does. My goal is to make grep find any number that matches a number inside the variable.

Comment: Could you give us an example of your df -h input and your expected output?

Comment: Hi Allan, sure.

Comment: Thanks will be able to answer if I have this information

Comment: Hey Allan, I have update the above post to give you what I got from df -h.

Comment: @Allan updated the above post for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider that `cat output_df` is the output of your `df -h` command:

```
$ cat output_df
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            481M     0  481M   2% /dev
tmpfs            99M  616K   98M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        25G  1.3G   23G   6% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   2% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.4M  102M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
```

Then you change the first part of your script in the following way:

```
thresold="2%|6%"
cat output_df | awk -v VAR=$thresold '{if($5~VAR)print $6}'
```

of course you will have to replace `cat output_df` by `df -h` in the final script.

This will give the output:

```
/dev
/
/dev/shm
/run/lock
```

Explanations:

- `thresold="2%|6%"` is a regex that matches `2%` or `6%` you can generalize it to `"2%|6%|X%|Y%|...|Z%"`
- You pass it as a variable to awk via `-v VAR=$thresold`
- Then you command `awk` to print the 6th field when the 5th field does match the regex that you have passed to it via `'{if($5~VAR)print $6}'`

Then you can regroup everything without using intermediate files:

```
thresold="2%|6%"
for f in `df -h | awk -v VAR=$thresold '{if($5~VAR)print $6}'`
do 
   find $f -xdev -size +40M -exec ls -lah {} \; 2>/dev/null | head -n10
done
```

On my box it gives the following output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47M  6月  1 06:33 /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47M  6月  1 06:33 /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 62M  4月 28 02:27 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 56M  2月 20 06:10 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73M  5月 22 19:31 /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 142M  5月 22 01:35 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41M  5月  8 09:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.28.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 54M 11月 17  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 99M  3月 18  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOxideQtCore.so.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42M  5月  8 09:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKitPluginProcess2
 ...
```

Notes: `2>/dev/null` this redirection is to remove all the permission errors by redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` (muting the `stderr`)

Comment: @allen, I have changed the code to the following as per your example:

    #!/bin/bash

    threshold="2%|6%"

    df -h > dffile

    grep $threshold dffile >> thresh

    cat thresh | awk -v VAR=$threshold '{if($5~VAR)print $6}' >> finding1

    LINES=()
    while IFS= read -r finding1
    do
    find $finding1 -xdev -size +40M -exec ls -lah {} \; | head -n 10
    done < "finding1"

However, as was intended, it is putting the output of df -h to dffile, but when it's supposed to grep for threshold and send it to the "thresh" file, it does not.

Comment: Oops. I'll have to put it up in the post.

Comment: @Blake Smreker: You can replace the 3 lines `df -h > dffile

grep $threshold dffile >> thresh

cat thresh | awk '{print $6}' >> finding1` directly by `thresold="2%|6%"
cat output_df | awk -v VAR=$thresold '{if($5~VAR)print $6}' > finding1`

Comment: @Allan Also note that `thresold="2%|6%"` must be `thresold="2%\|6%"` to use with `grep` which uses BRE. (basic regular expressions) You can use `egrep` (`grep -E`) to use extended regular expressions. (good effort and answer)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: thanks David! I have proposed an `awk` solution because it was an overkill to use that many intermediate files and since he was also using `awk` all of those steps could be regrouped in one call, anyway nice answer+1

Comment: Yes, I saw that in your answer, but didn't want to leave the Questioner thinking he could plug that into `grep` and make it work too `:)`

Comment: @Allan Thank you both for your help! I have edited my script, and I got it to work leaning towards Allan's answer. Thank you both for your time, and thank you Allan for the fast replies. Have a great evening!

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `threshold` as an *indexed array*,

```
threshold=("2%" "6%")
```

You then call `grep` with:

```
grep $threshold dffile
```

Since `threshold` is an array, to dereference all values in the array, you use the form:

```
${threshold[@]}   ## which can be quoted to preserve whitespace in elements
```

When you deference the array as a normal variable, e.g. `$threshold` you return only the 1st element, e.g.

```
echo $threshold  ##  output '2%'
```

So before going further, you need to determine what you want to pass to `grep`, if you want to search for either `2%` or `6%`, then Allan has a nice explanation above. You can also construct the `grep` expression using `printf -v`, e.g.

```
printf -v gexp "%s\|%s" ${threshold[@]}
```

or to properly limit to the first 2-elements,

```
printf -v gexp "%s\|%s" "${threshold[0]}" "${threshold[1]}"
```

and then call `grep` with

```
grep "$gexp" dffile >> thresh
```

Let me know if you have further questions.